# Problems in OpenModelica v1.19.2 when installing OpenHydraulics v1.0.1 with Modelica Standard Lib v3.2

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

Greeting Everyone, I am a new one here.

I'm a brand new Modelica user. I'm trying to learn the language with OpenModelica. I'd like to use OpenHydraulics which is in [github link](https://github.com/cparedis/OpenHydraulics) in OpenModelica (specifically in the OMEdit Connection Editor).

I downloaded OpenModelica v1.19.2 and Modelica Standard Lib v3.2 to browse and run the library OpenHydraulics v1.0.1. However, when I open the Excavator example and try to Instantiate or Simulate the model I get many errors of the form:

**[OpenHydraulics.Basic.VariableRestriction: 51:3-54:64]: Function ReynoldsNumber_m_flow not found in scope VariableRestriction.**

Could you help me with this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

there are a couple of things you need to take into consideration:

1. The current version of OpenHydraulics is still the original release from almost 10 years ago.
2. The library was developed using Dymola which at the time also supported a couple of non-standard Modelica, Dymola-specific constructs that other tools struggle to work with.
3. The example you are trying to run is the most complex one utilizing almost all of the power of the library and hence has quite a high degree of complexity.

Taking all this together means that OpenModelica is bound to struggle with that example. But all is not lost. If you actually look at the more simple circuit examples (under `Circuit`) you'll find that they work just fine. And depending on your application area they might already demonstrate a usage that will fit your needs.

I hope this helps.